# Select object from ARRAYLIST WITHOUT LOOP - ANDROID

Tags: java, android, lambdaj

I am looking for a library which can select object from ArrayList like SQL "where" command.

I have huge arraylists (between 2000 and 20000) in my project and i don't want to write for,while loops every time..

I found lambdaj and it is for Java.

I tried to use lambdaj inside my Android project but i couldn't do it.

For example when i write 
                                                                                          `List<Sale> sortedSales = sort(sales, on(Sale.class).getCost());`
  this example code in my project, eclipse couldn't see "sort", "on" commands..

Is there another library like lambdaj or can anyone tell me how can i use lambdaj in my android project ?

Thanks..

Comment: Why do you try to load data between 2k and 20k? From my exp. better to tell to SQL "from .. to"

Comment: Maxim is right. SQL is exactly for this purpose. What you could do with kludging arraylists would just waste memory and performance too compared to any SQL implementation...

Comment: I have to do this. I am already using SQL in my project. I am getting 20000 data from database for drawing. I am working with map and if user want to see every building in New York, i have to draw every building at New York and i have to put them into arraylist.

Comment: Make sure you have `import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.*;` in your source code file.

Comment: Important Note : lambdaj is **not working** for Android !!

Answer (score 1):

The [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library is much more popular than lambdaj, and does allow you to [avoid](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) for, while loops by using preficates and filter methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select an element that matches a criteria (or elementS that will match), use the Java 8 filter function. (no need to use other libraries anymore).

Do it as:

```
List<Foo> listOfFoo = ...
Stream<Foo> matchingFoo = listOfFoo.stream().filter(t -> t.propertyOrMethod == 'criteria');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [xpresso](https://github.com/WantedTechnologies/xpresso), you can write:

```
list<Sale> sortedSales = x.list(x.sorted(sales, x.invoke("getCost")));
```

(I am the author of xpresso)